# Pulsed NMR change in magnetisation vector

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy

When a second, radio frequency magnetic field $\ce{B1}$ is applied perpendicularly to $\ce{B0}$, why does the magnetisation vector M rotate in a direction perpendicular to both $\ce{B1}$ and $\ce{B0}$?

[image: Magnetisation vector rotation angle]

I understand how electric charges move in magnetic fields, and I understand the classical electromagnetism magnetic moment, but I can't figure out how $\ce{B1}$ move M in this direction.

Any help would be appreciated.

Image from http://chemistry.mit.edu/sites/default/files/DCIF-IntroNMRpart1-theory-o07.pdf

Answer (score 3):

In the nmr experiment the sample is placed into an intense but static magnetic field. By the (nuclear) Zeeman effect the spin energy levels that are degenerate in the absence of a magnetic field become split in energy and thus more spins reside in the lower energy levels that in higher one. The number of any level is given by the Boltzmann distribution at the prevailing temperature. The total spin angular momentum of the sample is called the magnetization. To make a measurement a magnetic field from a radio frequency source is applied at right angles to the large, static field. This tips the magnetization into the x-y plane making measurements possible. I try to explain how and what happens below.

The spins have a magnetic moment $\bar m$, which is a vector quantity meaning it has direction and magnitude, and as a result the static field causes magnetic induction $\bar B$ in the sample. This is also a vector. The magnetic induction (confusingly but commonly also called the magnetic field) is induced in the sample by the the large static magnetic field often labelled $H$.

If all the individual spin moments are added up these form the magnetization $ \bar M$. This is a magnetic field and is also a vector and so has both magnitude and direction.    All nuclear spin magnetic moments experiences a torque ( a rotational motion generating angular momentum ) in a magnetic field and is given by classical electromagnetism as $\bar m \times \bar B$ where $\times $ means this is a vector cross product; $\bar M \times \bar B=|M\|B|\sin(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors.  The change in angular momentum produced is given by $\displaystyle \frac{d\bar L}{dt}=\bar m\times B$. As the angular momentum is given by $\bar m=\gamma \bar L $,   where $\gamma$ is the magnetogyric ratio (these are known and for H is $27.75\cdot 10^{7}$ rad/T/s), then

$$ \frac{d\bar M}{dt}=\gamma \bar M\times B \tag{1}$$

This equation can be broken down into components in x, y and z directions. The z direction is conventionally taken as the direction along which $\bar B$ lies, and this has no x or y components. The three equations produced are

$$\frac{d M_x}{dt}=\gamma m_xB;\quad \frac{d M_y}{dt}=-\gamma m_yB; \quad \frac{d M_z}{dt}=0  \tag{2}$$

If there is no external perturbation then these equations show that the magnetization remains along the z axis and as we place the detector along the x or y axis then no signal can be observed. This is  because the magnetic field of the magnetization has to 'cut the coils' of the detector as so induce a signal that can be measured. It clearly cannot do this if it has magnitude only along the z axis.

The equations (2) can be solved if some initial conditions at time zero are chosen and physically important solutions are found only when the x and y components are not initially zero. In that case the solutions show that then magnetization in x and and y are proportional to $\sin(\omega_0t)$ and $\cos(\omega_0t)$ respectively where $\omega_0= \gamma B_0$ where $B_0$ is the z component of $\bar B$. The Larmor frequency is $\nu_0=\omega_0/(2\pi)$ and is the frequency measured in an nmr experiment.

As these solutions require that the magnetization has to be in the x-y plane this  condition has to be satisfied and is done so by exciting the sample with rf radiation directed along the x (or y) axis. This radiation has a magnetic  field that is weak compared to $\bar B$ and of magnitude $B_1$; its frequency we will call $\omega_r$. Classically the magnetic field applies a torque to the magnetization and rotates it away from the z axis.  In a molecular (quantum) explanation, if the rf energy is resonant with the energy gap, formed by the large static field $B$, then spins are excited from the lower to upper level and this changes both the size and direction of the magnetization $\bar M$.

In a classical  explanation the  polarised rf field $B_1$ is considered to be composed to two oppositely rotating fields. One moves in the same sense as the magnetization precesses, and so interacts with it, the other moves in the opposite sense and has little interaction and can be ignored. The experiment is now such that the spins experience both a static magnetic field $\bar B \equiv B_0$ in the z direction and a rotating field $B_1$ in the x-y plane. Clearly this is now a very complex problem but can be simplified if one assumes that the axes x and y rotate about z at the frequency of the $B_1$ magnetic field. This is called the 'rotating frame'. The result is that the equations similar to (1) are produced but with $B_{x,y,z} $ replaced by $B_{eff(x,y,z)}$ where $\displaystyle B_{eff}^2=(B_0-\frac{\omega_r}{\gamma})^2+B_1^2$.

Answer (score 3):

A more precise wording is that the magnetisation vector rotates about the applied field $\vec{B}_1$. This can be derived either classically or quantum mechanically.

I will start with a word of caution: fully understanding the images you have shown requires much more than this because there are certain concepts which are hidden. Without going into too much detail, the $B_1$ field is actually not static, but oscillates along one particular axis. This is decomposed into a sum of clockwise- and anticlockwise-rotating magnetic field. One of those two, say anticlockwise, is neglected because it is "off-resonance", and the frame of reference is taken to be a *rotating frame*, rotating clockwise at the same frequency as the clockwise half of the $B_1$ field, such that the clockwise $B_1$ field is static in this frame of reference. The last paragraph of porphyrin's answer gets towards this, but does not completely explain. (In no way is this a criticism, as the theory is rather involved, and I suggest reading a proper book on NMR theory, e.g. [Keeler's book.](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Understanding+NMR+Spectroscopy%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9780470746080))

---

porphyrin's answer already guides you through the classical approach, and I suppose any text on electromagnetism should also cover it. Without restating the answer fully, the crucial bit is the set of differential equations

$$\frac{\mathrm d\vec{M}}{\mathrm dt} = \gamma (\vec{M} \times \vec{B})$$

or more explicitly

$$\frac{\mathrm dM_x}{\mathrm dt} = \gamma (M_yB_z - B_yM_z) ; \quad \frac{\mathrm dM_y}{\mathrm dt} = \gamma (M_zB_x - B_zM_x) ; \quad \frac{\mathrm dM_z}{\mathrm dt} = \gamma (M_xB_y - B_xM_y)$$

Given (as in your diagram) $\vec{B} = (0, B, 0)$ as well as the initial condition $\vec{M}_{t = 0} = (0,0,M)$ you can then solve for $(M_x,M_y,M_z)$ as a function of time. You will get some sort of $\cos(\omega t)$ and $\sin(\omega t)$ dependency, where $\omega = -\gamma B$, which reflects the circular precession of the vector $\vec{M}$ about the vector $\vec{B}$ at the Larmor frequency $\omega$.

---

Quantum mechanically one can obtain the same relation for the precession of a single nuclear spin in a magnetic field. What you need to do is to use the time-dependent Schrödinger equation

$$\require{begingroup} \begingroup \newcommand{\wf}[0]{|\psi\rangle} \newcommand{\al}[0]{|\alpha\rangle} \newcommand{\be}[0]{|\beta\rangle} \newcommand{\ca}[0]{c_\alpha} \newcommand{\cb}[0]{c_\beta} 
\mathrm{i}\hbar \frac{\mathrm d\wf}{\mathrm dt} = \hat{H}\wf$$

In this case the Hamiltonian corresponding to a magnetic field along the $y$-axis is $\hat{H} = \omega\hat{I}_y$. The wavefunction for a single nuclear spin can most generally be written as a linear combination of up and down spin, $\al$ and $\be$ respectively:

$$\wf = \ca\al + \cb\be$$

where the coefficients $\ca$ and $\cb$ are time-dependent. Note that there should technically be a phase factor like $\exp(-\mathrm iEt/\hbar)$ in front of both $\ca$ and $\cb$, but in the rotating frame it so happens that $E_\alpha = E_\beta = 0$, so these phase factors disappear.

Now if we substitute this into the Schrödinger equation, and using the relations $\hat{I}_y\al = (\mathrm i\hbar/2)\be$ and $\hat{I}_y\be = (-\mathrm i\hbar/2)\al$ (these are most easily derived using the [Pauli spin matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices). Note that $I_y$ must include an additional factor of $\hbar/2$ relative to the $\sigma_y$ defined on Wikipedia), we get the following coupled differential equations:

$$\frac{\mathrm d\ca}{\mathrm dt} = -\frac{\omega}{2}\cb ; \quad \frac{\mathrm d\cb}{\mathrm dt} = \frac{\omega}{2}\ca $$

and you can once again solve these (using the initial boundary conditions $(\ca,\cb) = (1,0)$ at $t = 0$) to find the coefficients

$$\ca(t) = \cos\left(\frac{\omega t}{2}\right) ; \quad \cb(t) = \sin\left(\frac{\omega t}{2}\right)$$

The factor of half is probably a little worrying. However, note that the coefficients $\ca$ and $\cb$ do not reflect the actual magnetisation and hence the direction of the vector. To find this we must do one more step and find the expectation values of $\vec{I}$. This is demonstrated for the $x$-component:

$$\begin{align}
\langle I_x \rangle &= \langle \psi | I_x | \psi \rangle \\
&= \frac{\hbar}{2}\begin{pmatrix}\ca & \cb\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}\ca \\ \cb\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \frac{\hbar}{2}(\ca\cb + \cb\ca) \\
&= \frac{\hbar}{2}\left[2\cos\left(\frac{\omega t}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\omega t}{2}\right)\right] \\
&= \frac{\hbar}{2}\sin(\omega t)
\end{align}$$

Following the same procedure for $I_y$ and $I_z$ you can now readily demonstrate that the magnetisation vector for a single nuclear spin precesses in exactly the same fashion as a classical vector.

---

The only remaining issue is that NMR experiments are not performed on only one spin, but on a large number of spins, or an "ensemble" of spins. Intuitively this is not a huge problem, because one can imagine that each individual spin in the ensemble will behave exactly as described above, leading to an overall effect that behaves the same way (an overall magnetisation which precesses about the magnetic field $\vec{B}$).

Rigorously this would be shown using density matrices, denoted $\rho$. The entire explanation could well be another standalone answer, but suffice it to say here that the initial density matrix above is $\rho(0) = \hat{I}_z$. The Hamiltonian for a pulse applied along the $y$-axis, as before, is $\omega \hat{I}_y$. The effect of the Hamiltonian on the density matrix is described by the [Liouville–von Neumann equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix#The_von_Neumann_equation_for_time_evolution)

$$\mathrm i\hbar \frac{\mathrm d\rho}{\mathrm dt} = [H,\rho]$$

or its integrated form

$$\rho(t) = \exp\left(-\frac{iHt}{\hbar}\right) \rho(0) \exp\left(\frac{iHt}{\hbar}\right)$$

After substituting in the relevant matrices and operators, one finds that

$$\rho(t) = \exp\left(-\frac{i\omega t I_y}{\hbar}\right) I_z \exp\left(\frac{i\omega t I_y}{\hbar}\right)$$

After a bunch of mathematics it is possible to show that (for details, see e.g. Levitt *Spin Dynamics* 2nd ed., Appendix A.2 – beware that in NMR texts, $\hbar$ is usually taken to be unity. They will all cancel out anyway)

$$\rho(t) = I_z \cos(\omega t) + I_x \sin(\omega t)$$

as desired.